# How do I load ${catalina.home}/conf/application.properties in a Spring / Tomcat webapp?

Tags: spring, tomcat

How do I load `${catalina.home}/conf/application.properties` in a Spring / Tomcat webapp?

Looking around on StackOverflow and Google I see many discussions which claim it's possible.  However, it's just not working for me. In line with the advice from my research my Spring `applicationContext.xml` file contains the following line:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${catalina.home}/conf/application.properties"/>
```

But I get this in the logs:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/Users/username/Servers/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/conf/application.properties]
```

From the log entry I can see that `${catalina.home}` is expanding correctly. When I expand it by hand in the `applicationContext.xml` file it returns the same error. The following returns the contents of the application.properties file as expected:

```
cat /Users/username/Servers/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/conf/application.properties
```

So the path is clearly correct.  Is this a webapp security or Tomcat server configuration issue?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `location` of a `context:property-placeholder` is a *Resource*, which means that if you provide just a file path (as opposed to a full URL with a protocol) then the path will be resolved against the base directory of the webapp - it is trying to load `/Users/username/Servers/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/<appname>/Users/username/Servers/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/conf/application.properties`, which does not exist. If you prefix it with `file:` it'll work as you require:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${catalina.home}/conf/application.properties"/>
```

Comment: @lan in my case ${catalina.base} is not replaced by the actual path

Answer (score 13):

For annotation based configuration you can use:

```
@PropertySource("file:${catalina.home}/conf/application.properties")
```